# PHP preg_replace double quote not working

Tags: php, arrays, replace, preg-replace

I loaded a csv to array.
And I want to put " to column 21 if they don't have yet. This is sample of column 21. Some are empty. It's $data[21] in my case.

```
21
14"
14"
14"
empty
16"
```

This is my code

```
if (!str_contains($data[21], '"')) {
$data[21] = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/',$data[21].'"',$data[21]);
}
```

But the result is

```
21"
14"
14''"''
14''"''
empty
16''"''
```

Only the first two and the empty ones are correct. What's wrong with this? Thanks.

**EDIT.. Please read comment**

After helps from everyone, I realized some of the data was actually bad. They use 2 single quotes instead of double quotes.
So actually this code works, as well as suggestions from Nick. Thanks.

Comment: Not clear what you're trying to do but I don't think you need a regex for that.

Comment: The input and output data are not clear.

Comment: I want to put double quote (") to the numbers only if they don't already have one.

Comment: Why not just `$data[21] .= '"'` inside the `if`?

Comment: And why did you put the `arrays` tag?

Comment: @Nick then it adds " to anything, even the empty ones. And strangely the 14" is correct, but the rest gives 14''" now.

Comment: Just test if the string is empty or not.

Comment: @Olivier Some of the data have numbers without double quote, example 21. Some already have double quotes, example 14" and 16". Some are empty.
I need to put double quote to 21 because it does not have yet.
If the test only for empty, then 21 will not be detected.

Comment: If the string is not empty and the last character is not `"`, then append a `"`.

Comment: Can you show me how to code that in php please?

Comment: @Pekzz can you show us a couple of realistic lines from your csv file before you parse it into an array?  Where is the csv file being created, anyhow?  Are you in control of its creation/content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace) with the following regex:

```
(?<=\d)$
```

which will match end-of-string when it is preceded by a digit. In PHP:

```
$data[21] = preg_replace('/(?<=\d)$/', '"', $data[21]);
```

Demo on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/fdUng)

Based on your sample data, I've assumed the values are made up of digits. If not, then you need to check that what precedes end-of-line is not a `"` or beginning of line, which you can do with this regex:

```
(?<!"|^)$
```

Demo on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9pGEe)

In both cases, for your sample data the output is:

```
21"
14"
14"
14"

16"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Nick. After testing and still got some unwanted results, I found out some of the data were bad. Instead of double quote, they have 2 single quotes. For example the bad 14" was written 14'' initially. That's why both my original question and this solution did not work at first. Sorry for false question and thank you again for your help, so I can realized this. Cheers..!!

Comment: @Pekzz ah, what a pain - on a non fixed-width font they would look pretty similar. Anyway, I'm glad this was helpful. Note (in case it wasn't clear) that with this code you don't need the `if (!str_contains($data[21], '"'))` statement.

Comment: wow.. I didn't know this doesn't need "if". Thanks for pointing this out. I'll use this instead.

Comment: @Pekzz note you can even deal with the two single quotes problem: https://3v4l.org/24OvM